# Laravel 5.1: Guzzle 6 return response is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, guzzle6

I'm using Gazzle 6 with Laravel 5.1 and I'm having a strange behaviour returning my data from the APIs I'm using. This is my code:

```
$data = array(
    'id' => '112233'
);

$from = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(1)->format('d/m/Y');
$to = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->subMonths(1)->format('d/m/Y');

$first_report = $this->client->post('https://my.service.com/reporting/execute/', [
    'auth' => ['myemail@email.com', 'mypassword'],
    'form_params' => ['data' => json_encode($data)]
]);



$second_report = $this->client->get('mysecondservice.com/reports', [
    'query' => [
        'account_auth_token' => '000011122223333444455556667778889999',
        'start_date' => $to,
        'end_date' => $from
    ]
]);

return array(
    'first_report' => $first_report,
    'second_report' => $second_report
);
```

If I return the data as an array like the previous one the **first_report** and **second_report** are empty. But if I return only for example

```
return $first_report;
```

or

```
return $second_report;
```

The data is returned correctly for each report but I don't know what is the issue there, because I have tried with: **json_encode** or even **return $response()->json...** but still not working.

Do you have any idea about what's going on?

Comment: What does `echo gettype($first_report);` give you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to run the `send()` function on the object you have to get the response, then run `getBody()` on that to get the response object, then run `getContents()` on that to get the contents of the response as a string.  So in total it would look like

```
$first_report = $this->client->post('https://my.service.com/reporting/execute/', [
'auth' => ['myemail@email.com', 'mypassword'],
'form_params' => ['data' => json_encode($data)]
])->send()->getBody()->getContents();



$second_report = $this->client->get('mysecondservice.com/reports', [
'query' => [
    'account_auth_token' => '000011122223333444455556667778889999',
    'start_date' => $to,
    'end_date' => $from
]
])->send()->getBody()->getContents();
```

I find the Guzzle documentation does not match up with the actual methods I use to get the results.  Not sure if it's out of date or if I'm doing it wrong, but this method works for me.

Comment: I just found the right function which is: ->getBody()->getContents() because ->send()->getBody(true); didn't work.

Comment: Glad you got it working! According to the docs getBody() returns a body object, whereas getBody(true) returns a string with the contents of the body.

Comment: Yes, thank you! You should to update your answer using the method I used so others users with the same issue can see the right one.